# Sitecore - set controls order in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I want to change controls order in presentation details for one placeholder. I got renderings using `NewsletterHeader["__Renderings"]` and I had this:

```xml
<r xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">
  <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
    <r uid="{042E3CC4-8205-4A1D-85F4-7D667622711D}" s:ds="" s:par="" s:ph="masterplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{B19D0460-69C9-4FEC-A882-41FFA77B582F}" p:before="r[@uid='{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/Polecane" s:id="{C3AC52FB-8F51-4B44-A3EE-55F4C2EAF83F}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />            
    <r uid="{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}" p:before="r[@uid='{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/HITY" s:id="{7A80D822-8D6A-40C4-92D4-2FA22C596339}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />            
    <r uid="{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}" p:before="r[@uid='{B6036949-B723-42CE-9271-64DF299450DC}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/VOD" s:id="{557800E7-953B-4830-8691-3FFB964712A8}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />         
    <r uid="{B6036949-B723-42CE-9271-64DF299450DC}" p:before="r[@uid='{CC44C44C-B10C-417A-8E19-43B57AAD4C93}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/BANER" s:id="{AE048833-A8AF-4668-938A-FEBA48281620}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />           
    <r uid="{CC44C44C-B10C-417A-8E19-43B57AAD4C93}" p:before="r[@uid='{F75C5CBE-60E2-4A0A-87F6-B6AB46AC2E52}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/JESZCZE-WIECEJ-HITOW" s:id="{D5FCDC02-C2A8-47A9-BCF5-99A3DF7E8A25}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />            
    <r uid="{F75C5CBE-60E2-4A0A-87F6-B6AB46AC2E52}" s:id="{71B654BA-5F47-4053-8936-7199C34E55E4}" s:ph="footerplaceholder" />
  </d>
</r>
```

Then I tried to change its order in C# using this code:

```csharp
private void SetSectionsOrder()
{
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        //Get the value of the __renderings field
        string renderingXml = this.NewsletterHeader["__Renderings"];
        XNamespace nsS = "s";
        XNamespace nsP = "p";
        //Get order from model
        var order = this.Newsletter.GetSectionsOrder();
        //Generate XDcoument from xml
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(renderingXml);
        for (int i = 0; i < order.Count; i++)
        {
            var section = order[i];
            if (i == 0)
            {
                XElement sectionElement = xd.Descendants("r").FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ds") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ds").Value.Contains(section.Item1));
                XElement footerElement = xd.Descendants("r").FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ph") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ph").Value == "footerplaceholder");
                if (footerElement != null)
                {
                    string footerUid = footerElement.Attribute("uid").Value;
                    if (sectionElement != null)
                        sectionElement.Attribute(nsP + "before").SetValue("r[@uid='" + footerUid + "']");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var prevSection = order[i - 1];
                XElement sectionElement = xd.Descendants("r").FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ds") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ds").Value.Contains(section.Item1));
                XElement prevSectionElement = xd.Descendants("r").FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Attribute(nsS + "ds") != null) && e.Attribute(nsS + "ds").Value.Contains(prevSection.Item1));
                if (prevSectionElement != null)
                {
                    string prevSectionUid = prevSectionElement.Attribute("uid").Value;
                    if (sectionElement != null)
                        sectionElement.Attribute(nsP + "before").SetValue("r[@uid='" + prevSectionUid + "']");
                }
            }
        }
        //Save new order   
        this.NewsletterHeader.Editing.BeginEdit();
        this.NewsletterHeader["__Renderings"] = xd.ToString();
        this.NewsletterHeader.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

As a result I received this xml:

```xml
<r xmlns:p="p" xmlns:s="s" p:p="1">
  <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}">
    <r uid="{042E3CC4-8205-4A1D-85F4-7D667622711D}" s:ds="" s:par="" s:ph="masterplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{B19D0460-69C9-4FEC-A882-41FFA77B582F}" p:before="r[@uid='{F75C5CBE-60E2-4A0A-87F6-B6AB46AC2E52}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/Polecane" s:id="{C3AC52FB-8F51-4B44-A3EE-55F4C2EAF83F}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}" p:before="r[@uid='{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/HITY" s:id="{7A80D822-8D6A-40C4-92D4-2FA22C596339}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{4D8EE7B4-E1D2-4CBF-AED7-5E969EFAA57A}" p:before="r[@uid='{B19D0460-69C9-4FEC-A882-41FFA77B582F}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/NCPlus/Strony/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/VOD" s:id="{557800E7-953B-4830-8691-3FFB964712A8}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{B6036949-B723-42CE-9271-64DF299450DC}" p:before="r[@uid='{CC44C44C-B10C-417A-8E19-43B57AAD4C93}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/BANER" s:id="{AE048833-A8AF-4668-938A-FEBA48281620}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{CC44C44C-B10C-417A-8E19-43B57AAD4C93}" p:before="r[@uid='{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}']" s:ds="/sitecore/content/emagazyn/emagazyn-cplus/JESZCZE-WIECEJ-HITOW" s:id="{D5FCDC02-C2A8-47A9-BCF5-99A3DF7E8A25}" s:par="" s:ph="moviesplaceholder" />
    <r uid="{F75C5CBE-60E2-4A0A-87F6-B6AB46AC2E52}" s:id="{71B654BA-5F47-4053-8936-7199C34E55E4}" s:ph="footerplaceholder" />
  </d>
</r>
```

And this is what I wanted to get. But when I enter presentation details in Sitecore, there is order like this:

- BANER
- JESZCZE-WIECEJ-HITOW
- HITY
- VOD
- Polecane
- footerplaceholder

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to change this order?

Answer (score 6):

The order is determined by the `uid` and `p:before` attributes, so the results make sense.

For example, the `BANER` node specifies that it should appear before the node with a `uid` of `{CC44C44C-B10C-417A-8E19-43B57AAD4C93}`, which is `JESZCZE-WIECEJ-HITOW`

The `JESZCZE-WIECEJ-HITOW` node specifies that it should appear before the node with a `uid` of `{D43901A0-1B71-4C65-BEED-DDCF28FCE5A5}`, which is `HITY`.

The only node without a `p:before` attribute is `footerplaceholder` and as expected, it appears last.

So following these rules, they are all listing in the correct order.

It's worth noting that there is a `LayoutDefinition` class in Sitecore. So you don't need to deal with the XML directly.

```csharp
var ld = new LayoutDefinition();
ld.LoadXml(this.NewsletterHeader["__Renderings"]);
```

Check thse articles out for more information on using the class:

- [PROGRAMMATICALLY UPDATE LAYOUT DETAILS WITH THE SITECORE ASP.NET
  CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/09/programmatically-update-layout-details-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)
- [Programmatically set layouts in Sitecore](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2011/07/Programmatically-set-layout-in-sitecore.aspx)

Comment: I think I don't get it. You tell that I did it properly, but the result order is still wrong. So what should I do to get the order I wanted to get?

Comment: Maybe elements order in xml are important too?

Comment: I didn't mean your code is correct, juat that the output is what I would expect from the XML provided. If the results are not what you wanted then you need to consider manipulating the `uid` and `p:before` attributes or using the `LayoutDefinition` class.

Comment: Can I set uid whatever I want?